# Counting lottery odds - question about the code

Tags: java, for-loop, math, java.util.scanner

I was analyzing the following code concerning Lottery Odds and I have 2 questions:

- why do we need to set lotteryOdds' value to 1 first (also, is it a usual situation in calculations of this type?)
- I know the formula used for counting the odds (n*(n-1)...(n-k+1)/(1*2...*k), but if someone explained me how it works in accordance to repeating the "for" loop, I'd appreciate.

  ```
  import java.util.Scanner;

    public class LotteryOdds {


        public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println(" How many numbers do you need to draw? ");
        int k = in.nextInt();

        System.out.println(" what is the highest numbers you can do draw? ");
        int n = in.nextInt();

        int lotteryOdds = 1;

        for (int i = 1; i <= k; i++) {
            lotteryOdds = lotteryOdds * (n - i + 1) / i;

            System.out.println("Your odds are 1 in " + lotteryOdds + " . Good luck!");
        }

    }
  ```

  }

Comment: Think about what would happen if `lotteryOdds` was 0: `lotteryOdds = 0 * (whatever)` will result in... 0. :)

Comment: Yes, I understand that, but why do we need to define it then.

Comment: Wouldn't the formula be rather `n!/(k! * (n-k)!)`? That would mean you need to calculate 3 factorials: `n!`, `k!` and `(n-k)!` - so all you need is a method that uses one loop to calculate a factorial.

Comment: "why do we need to define it" - that's because your code needs it, i.e. at some point you would have to define the variable (and your code would require it right away or how would you calculate `odds * whatever` if `odds` isn't defined? And you _need_ to  initialize any local variable in any case or you wouldn't be able to use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `lotteryOdds` variable needs to be 1, because if you do 0 * something you will always get 0, so the program will always return 0.
As for the loop, lets change the values and go trough the loop:
First iteration:

> lotteryOdds = 1 * (n - 1 + 1) / 1 = n / 1

Second iteration:

> lotteryOdds = n * ((n - 2 + 1) / 2) = (n / 1) * ((n - 1) / 2) = n *
> ((n - 1) / 2) = ((n * (n - 1)) / (1 * 2)

Etc.
So when you generalize it you get:
(n * (n - 1)...(n - k + 1) / (1 * 2 ... * k) just like in the formula above.